# URL Schemes-sending action ios

Tags: ios, button, dynamic, launch, url-scheme

I have devoleped 3 applications,one of them called Main-app and it contains icons of the two others app and a button to access to thew from the main-app.the problem is that if I want to add an app from the app store,how can I get the icon and create a button dynamically into the main-app? I suggest to use URL Schemes between apps but I dont know how to do it.

Comment: If its possible,please tell me how can I implement it

Comment: You need to clarify your question. It's actually pretty vague. I thought you wanted one thing but after seeing your comments it seems you want something else. Update your question (not in comments) with more specific details about what you want to do. Also include what you've done and explain what isn't working for you.

Comment: ok thanks,I d do it right now

Comment: I specifically said to update your question and not to post it as a comment.

Comment: Can you telle me how its possible? rmaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to have all the app names and icons in each app's bundle and differentiate them using the "sourceApplication" parameter of the `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` method of UIApplicationDelegate

Comment: thanks...but I don't see how to add button in the receiver app calling  it

Comment: By button do you mean something similar to the green bar for an active call?

Comment: I have an application that manage others,If I want to add an app  to the main app,its icon and a button can opent it should be created in the app name

Comment: sorry..I mean the app main

Comment: If I am not misunderstanding this you have an app that opens other apps using the URL scheme method? If that is the case and you want to check if a new app developed by you is installed on the phone you can use the 'canOpenURL:' method of the UIApplication class to detect the new app and add a button to your main app UI to open it. I hope that helps! :)

Comment: I'll add the button manually?I want that will be dynamic and when a new app is installed,have its icon and a button to open it(in the main-app)...thanks

Comment: When the app is opened run a check for apps and update your UI to have the installed apps corresponding buttons. But yeah you have to do it yourself it's you apps and logics :)